# Query Sum of jsonb column of objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a `jsonb` column on my DB called `reactions` which has the structure like below.

```json
[
   {
     "id": "1234",
     "count": 1
   },
   {
     "id": "2345",
     "count": 1
   }
]
```

The field holds an array of objects, each with a `count` and `id` field. I'm trying to find which object in the `reactions` field has the highest count across the db. Basically, I'd like to sum each object by it's id and find the max.

I've figured out how to sum up all of the reaction counts, but I'm getting stuck grouping it by the ID, and finding the sum for each individual id.

```sql
SELECT SUM((x->>'count')::integer) FROM (SELECT id, reactions FROM messages) as m
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(m.reactions) AS x
```

Ideally I'd end up with something like this:

```sql
id   | sum 
-----------
1234 | 100
2345 | 70
5678 | 50
```

The `messages` table looks something like this

```sql
id | user | reactions
------------------------
1  | 3456 | jsonb
2  | 8573 | jsonb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data calculation needs to take some transformation steps.

1. flat the `jsonb` column from `array` to individual `jsonb` objects using `jsonb_array_elements` function ;

```sql
postgres=# select jsonb_array_elements(reactions)::jsonb as data from messages;
            data            
----------------------------
 {"id": "1234", "count": 1}
 {"id": "2345", "count": 1}
 {"id": "1234", "count": 1}
 {"id": "2345", "count": 1}
...
```

2. populate each `jsonb` objects to seperate columns with `jsonb_populate_record` function ;

```sql
postgres=# create table data(id text ,count int);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# select r.* from (select jsonb_array_elements(reactions)::jsonb as data from messages) as tmp, jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data) r;
  id  | count 
------+-------
 1234 |     1
 2345 |     1
 1234 |     1
 2345 |     1
...
```

3. do the `sum` with `group by`.

```sql
postgres=# select r.id, sum(r.count) from (select jsonb_array_elements(reactions)::jsonb as data from messages) as tmp, jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data) r group by r.id;
  id  | sum 
------+-----
 2345 |   2
 1234 |   2
...
```

The above steps should make it.

Comment: Perfect this worked like a charm, thank you for the great explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below - to convert the jsonb array to standard rows

see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203250/getting-specific-key-values-from-jsonb-into-columns

```
select "id", sum("count")
  from messages
  left join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(reactions) x ("id" text, "count" int) on true
group by "id" order by 1;
```